# Copiando registro da tabela nela mesma via vba

Tags: sql, microsoft-access, vba

Dá pra copiar um registro de uma tabela e inserir nela mesma?
Eu queria copiar um registro num novo na mesma tabela.

```sql
INSERT INTO Produtos ( Produto, Preco )
SELECT Produtos.Produto, Produtos.Preco
FROM Produtos
WHERE (((Produtos.Produto)="AN001"));
```

Comment: Olá! Por curiosidade, você tentou executar já isto, e qual foi o resultado? alguma mensagem de erro ?

Comment: Esse código retorna algum erro?

Comment: Se você está tendo dificuldades com isso, talvez seja porque está duplicando a *Primary Key*. Geralmente as ferramentas SQL permitem esse tipo de código, mas isso só funcionaria na forma da pergunta se você tiver um código (ID) com *auto incremento*.

Comment: @utluiz eu ia comentar sobre chaves, mas achei melhor esperar uma mudança na pergunta (mais detalhes: funcionou ou não? com qual erro?) para depois dar uma resposta. Tenho quase certeza que o seu comentário é a resposta para a pergunta

Comment: Regis, não edite o título para "Resolvido". Poste a sua solução e marque-a como certa.

Comment: Não edites a pergunta para aplicar a resposta... Sugiro que alteres a pergunta de forma a que fique com o código necessário para se notar o erro que descobriste e posteriormente a isso, colocas uma resposta dando conta da solução, marcando a mesma como a resposta correcta, fechando assim este assunto. :)

Comment: Deverias adicionar uma resposta, em vez de alterar a pergunta.

Comment: Estou tentando entender o que está acontecendo com essa pergunta em http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/o-que-esta-acontecendo-com-uma-pergunta-ja-resolvida

Comment: Não consigo postar uma resposta para mim mesmo, mas como afirmei. Já foi resolvido, e a resposta correta encontra-se logo na sequencia.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva Estamos tentando reabrir a pergunta, aí então você poderá postar uma resposta. Se você preferir, pode também simplesmente excluir a pergunta (i.e. se você achar que não tem muita utilidade manter a pergunta no site; mas não estou dizendo que é isso que precisa ser feito - a decisão é só sua!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Resposta originalmente postada pelo autor da pergunta, na própria pergunta**

Foi só um erro de sintaxe, segue o código correto:

```vba
sql = "INSERT INTO Produtos ( Produto, Preco )" _
    & " SELECT '" & Me.CodProduto & "', Preco" _
    & " FROM Produtos" _
    & " WHERE Produto='" & Me.ListaProduto & "';"
```